# Fullscreen menu - Hide scrollbar but allow me to scroll with wheel or finger

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a fullscreen menu. When it appears, some of the elements are not visible, unless I give the menu an `overflow-y: scroll` property. The problem is that I don't like the look of that second scrollbar for the menu.

[image]

How can I remove it but still be able to scroll through the menu items. It's important to keep the menu fulls creen, I tried changing from "fixed" position to "absolute" but then it just kept scrolling trough the website and didn't look fullscreen at all. I don't mind the website scrolling behind the menu, as long as the menu is the only thing visible.

My code:

```
<header>
<div id="logo-container">
    <img src="http://localhost/theinsidervox/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logo.png" alt="The Insider Vox">
</div>

<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-19"> <a href="http://localhost/theinsidervox/">Inicio</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-28"><a href="#">First Test Menu Item</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-29"><a href="#">Second Test Menu Item</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-30"><a href="#">Third Test Menu Item</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-21"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-22"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Plain</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-23"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Videos</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-24"><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Galleries</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>    

</header>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header and Menu */
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
header.menu-open {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

ul.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header.menu-open ul.menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
ul.menu li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
ul.menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 52px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.7;
    color: #0f0f0f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

jQuery just to add the OPENED class:

```
$('#logo-container img').click(function() {
    $('header').addClass('menu-open');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I handle this personally in my own site is to hide the scroll bar for the body when the menu is open. So, when I open the menu, I add a class to the body:

```
$(document.body).addClass("menu-open");
```

And, in my CSS:

```
body.menu-open {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Finally, when closing the menu:

```
$(document.body).removeClass("menu-open");
```

Then, you can add overflow-y to your menu, and it'll work as intended.

I do it this way instead of just having the menu show its overflow because I like to restrict the scrolling of the user to just the menu - they shouldn't be able to scroll past it.

Comment: This actually works. As long as it gets rid of two ugly scrollbars I'm happy!